# Make a Greek letter with a subscript appear in an Input message

Tags: output, latex, string-manipulation

I've got a variable that has two names on it. It is defined as follows:

`par={b, Subscript[λ, 0]}`

I would like to ask the user to enter a value of the second variable inside `par`. What I am currently doing is

```
input=Input["Enter a value for parameter " <> ToString[par[[2]],StandardForm]]
```

The problem is that the input message appears in this way:

[image: Input message]

That is not a fancy way to show the message. How can I show the parameter `par[[2]]` as in LaTeX output?

Comment: `input = Input[StringForm["Enter a value for parameter ``", par[[2]]]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is much better to use [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row) instead of [`ToString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToString) and [`StringJoin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringJoin), so I would recommend:

```
input = Input[Row[{"Enter a value for parameter ", par[[2]]}]]
```

However, if you absolutely must work with strings, you can do:

```
input = Input[StandardForm["Enter a value for parameter "<>ToString[par[[2]],StandardForm]]]
```